# how makemessages command address templates outside of project folder for *.po files

Tags: python, django

this is my directory structure:

```
Implementaion\template 
Implementaion\Agency_project\locale
Implementaion\Agency_project\airAgency_app
```

when running `django-admin.py makemessages -l fa` it just collect translation tags from `Agency_project` folder,I don't know how to associate it with my template folder that contains my html files and is beside of `Agency_project` folder.
I've just found `--symlink` that it didn't work,or may I couldn't use it!

Answer (score 0):

No, my experience is also that somehow makemessages does not use symlinks. And it does not want to mix project-wide translations with app translations which I think is quite sane.

The solution is to do "cd airAgency_app" and then "../manage.py makemessages -l fa". Just remember to create a locale folder in your airAgency_app.

The key is to think your translations as a per-app thing. And then what you have of translations in your project templates/ folder can go in the project-wide translation folder.